# Using method from library included by use

Tags: php

I need to use method from Nette library, that I'm including by `use` command. But it doesn't work as I want to, throws fatal error, that I am calling undefined method.
How should I approach that method to make it work? Stupid question, but I am kinda new to OOP...

Method from class `PresenterComponent.php`

```
public function getPresenter($need = TRUE)
{
    return $this->lookup('Nette\Application\UI\Presenter', $need);
}
```

And my code, where I need to use that method:

```
use Nette\Application\UI\PresenterComponent;

class DatabaseCollectionAdapter extends ArrayDataAdapter
{
// ..... some code......
$this->user = $this->getPresenter()->getUser();
```

Error:

```
Fatal Error

Call to undefined method Ctech\Gridator\DataAdapter\DatabaseCollectionAdapter::getPresenter()
```

Comment: copy and paste the complete error into your question please.

Comment: @TobiasF. Done, there it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$this->user = $this->getPresenter()->getUser();
```

to this:

```
$object = new yourObject(); // yourObject extends PresenterComponent
$this->user = $object->getPresenter()->getUser();
```

Comment: 2) getPresenter() is located in PresenterComponent

Comment: I can't do that, because it's abstract class.. but I saw in other classes, that they are using this method..

Comment: If "PresenterComponent"  is abstract and you have other class that extend it - you can use it without "PresenterComponent"

Answer (score 0):

`use Nette\Application\UI\PresenterComponent;` does not include or do any kind of magic to make it's functions available on the fly.

https://secure.php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.importing.php

It's just a shorthand that helps you to use `PresenterComponent` directly without specifying the whole namespace.

Your `DatabaseCollectionAdapter` or `ArrayDataAdapter` has to have a function that looks like this:

```
class AdapterClass

  public function getPresenter() {
    return new Nette\Application\UI\PresenterComponent;
  }

}
```

or something like this

```
use Nette\Application\UI\PresenterComponent;

class AdapterClass

  public function getPresenter() {
    return new PresenterComponent;
  }

}
```